# Clicking overlapping Markers triggers onMarkerClick for all of them.

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a map with markers that sit pretty close to each other sometimes. When tapping one the click event also occurs on the markers that sit behind the one that was clicked. The listener is implemented as follows.:

```
googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                        presenter.onMarkerClicked(activeMarkers.get(marker.getId())
                                                               .getModelId());
                        return true;
                    }
                });
```

Is there a way to avoid this without introducing extra state to my fragment?

Comment: Implement the info window and onclick of info window do your action.

Comment: not an option i use a bottomsheet to display the marker information and i open it through that click.

Comment: In that case, you have to manually handle the click with a flag. I mean store the click event and put the check before another marker gets click.

Comment: i was really hoping not to be forced to do this. ^^ Let's see if someone comes up with a better way, otherwise i will close this question.

Comment: try to just override the function onMarkerClick in your Map Activitiy..but not inside in another click listener

Comment: I am using com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap and com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to make tags for your markers so you can identify them... each marker has a setTag ..utilize that so you can differentiate them in the listener.